# Can import cause crash/error after compilation?

Tags: java, import

Like in title.

Example: I have program with 3 classes:
Server, Client, Main.

Main has 2 imports - Server and Client.
Depending on in what mode I launch the program (client or server) the Main class will use method from given class.

Now let's say I remove Server.class from .jar - will the program crash if I run it in Client mode? I am not using any methods from removed class (it's blocked by if(...), there is just its import there and unused reference blocked by if ofc.

Comment: An `import` statement is purely a compile time feauture. It lets you use the short names of types. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

If the program never reaches the part that uses the server class when running in the "client mode", the program will normally run fine without crashing, since the JVM would only load a classfile when the class is used.

However, as soon as the server class is referenced in any other condition, the program will crash with a `NoClassDefFoundError` so this solution imposes risks.